# Pytorch won't install on Windows 11

Tags: python, pytorch, llama

I need Pytorch for LLAMA AI, but Pytorch won't install. I'm currently getting this error when I try to install Pytorch 2.1.0 on windows 11 CPU with pip for Python. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (From versions: None) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch. I've already tried conda package. I'm on the latest version of Python, but I've also tried downgrading.

I've tried downgrading Python, installing other software, and more.

Comment: Show us the exact command you used.

Comment: pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

Comment: _I've tried downgrading Python_ How exactly did you do this?

Comment: Directly from the Python.org site, and I always used the windows installer (64-bit). I think The lowest I've downgraded was to 3.10.0 from following instructions on YouTube. I have the latest version of pip, numpy. I have visual studio community edition. Visual studio build tools, and more installed. I'm trying to figure out which dependencies I'm missing.

Comment: When you downgraded python, did you uninstall the existing one?  Or did you install a new earlier version in addition to the one you were using first?

Comment: I uninstalled the newer version before installing the old versions. I'm now on the latest version of Python and pip. I'm currently installing dependencies. My current goal is to install all of the dependencies and softwares needed to install and use Pytorch. I just instaled CLANG from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Comment: I finally got it installed after watching this YT video. It seems like installing softwares with popular packages like Anaconda is the way. https://youtu.be/4dNmxXl4QvY